# How can I install react-native-contacts?

Tags: react-native-contacts

I'm having issues installing react-native-contacts. How is this done?

react-native: 0.49.3
react-native-contacts: 2.1.1

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find installation instructions at https://github.com/rt2zz/react-native-contacts#installation basically you can install react-native-contacts via [react native link](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md#react-native-link) or you can link the project manually. Same as any other native module for react native.